# Android, MySQL, Runtime

Tags: android, mysql

I am using the [following code](http://blog.sptechnolab.com/2011/02/10/android/android-connecting-to-mysql-using-php/) to connect to a MySQL DB and simply display the results. The issue must be in the API, but I dont see it and it works for others. I have modified the code accordingly for my DB. Here is the runtime error from DDMS.

06-24 13:45:24.537: E/AndroidRuntime(32329): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.list/com.list.TestdbActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.list.TestdbActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.list-2.apk]

Comment: Do you have your activity registered in the manifest file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok you should add the Activity that you are using into the manifest:) you should still add is as `<activity android:name=".TestdbActivity"></activity>`

Comment: Just Activity? Can you explain this a little more?

Comment: <activity
            android:name=".testdbActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Comment: so is this your main activity?

Comment: just saw the capitalization error...still have the runtime after correcting it

Comment: dude you have typed the class name with small "t" . replace  .testdbActivity ----with----> .TestdbActivity

Comment: Still getting the same error...going to start fresh and see whats up...thanks for your help!